# estimating confidence interval for same value in a variable

Tags: r

I have data frame named `df`. I want to calculate confidence interval 0.95  for the variable `gp` based on `res` and `gender`. my expected form of data would be like `df1`.

```
df<- data.frame(res = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                gender = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                gp=c(10.1,10.5,11.2,9.8,9.7,8.9,7.6,8.8,6.6,5.5,4.4,4.9,3.2,2.3,4.9,6.8))
```

expected data=

```
df1<- 

res   gender    upper    lower
1       1        
2       1
3       1
4       1
1       2
2       2
3       2
4       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with `aggregate`.

```
ci <- function(x, conf = 0.95){
  lo <- (1 - conf)/2
  up <- 1 - lo
  qq <- qnorm(c(lo, up), mean(x), sd(x))
  c(lower = qq[1], upper = qq[2])
}
agg <- aggregate(gp ~ res + gender, df, ci)
agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])

agg
#  res gender      lower    upper
#1   1      1  3.4993366 13.20066
#2   2      1  1.0704809 14.92952
#3   3      1 -1.6241460 17.22415
#4   4      1  0.5590713 14.14093
#5   1      2 -2.5583749 15.45837
#6   2      2 -3.5469652 14.74697
#7   3      2  2.5080597  9.99194
#8   4      2  5.0281924 10.57181
```

---

### Edit

Here is a way to call the function `ci` multiple time, with several confidence levels.

```
confLevels <- c(0.80, 0.90, 0.95)
lst <- lapply(confLevels, function(x){
  agg <- aggregate(gp ~ res + gender, df, ci, conf = x)
  agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])
  names(agg)[3:4] <- paste(names(agg)[3:4], x, sep = ".")
  agg
  
})
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), lst)
```

Comment: thanks @ Rui Barradas it works. is there any way to add another level of confidence interval such as 0.80 and 0.90 ?